# Smartface crashing upon debug (idb.exe)

Tags: smartface.io

When trying to debug a very simple app on Windows 7, the fresh install of Smartface, fresh version of iTunes, Profile: iOS, Device: iPhone5(s), clicking Debug button, idb.exe crashes straight away and displays a message "idb.exe The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close application".

Smartface was sort of working until the fresh version of iTunes was installed (12 instead of 11).

Comment: Uninstalling of iTunes and re-installing the same latest version of Smartface with the iTunes that came together with Smartface did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

iTunes libraries are changed with iTunes 12 because of that reason idb.exe is crashing.

idb.exe is fixed for iTunes 12 and it will be announced with Smartface App Studio 4.3.0

You can read the Release Note from http://www.smartface.io/release-notes/v-4-3-0/